# Haskell code zipWith using Maybe

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with this code. I'm trying to write a simple function that takes two lists and tries to divide each element of list A by the corresponding element of list B. If the element in list B is 0, it should return `Nothing`, otherwise it should return `Just (a / b)`.

Here is the code:

```
divlist :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
divlist = zipWith (\x y -> if (y /= 0) then Just (x / y) else Nothing)
```

It's probably something stupid, but I simply can't find it.

EDIT: This is what ghci is reporting:

```
C:\Users\spravce\Desktop\Haskell\6.hs:16:51: error:
    • Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from a use of ‘/’
    from the context: Integral a
        bound by the type signature for:
                divlist :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
        at C:\Users\spravce\Desktop\Haskell\6.hs:14:1-48
    Possible fix:
        add (Fractional a) to the context of
        the type signature for:
            divlist :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [Maybe a]
    • In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘(x / y)’
    In the expression: Just (x / y)
    In the expression: if (y /= 0) then Just (x / y) else Nothing
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

EDIT 2:
Using `div x y` instead of `x / y` just did it. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are specifying an `Integral` constraint on your function, but using `(/)` inside the function which signifies fractional division.

You probably want to use `div`, which is integral division, e.g. `` 3 `div` 2 == 1 ``. Otherwise, change the constraint from `Integral` to `Fractional` (which is what the error message is telling you to do).